# 3D jagged Array

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, jagged-arrays

Is there a way to access my three dimensional jagged array like this:

```
jaggedArray[1,2,3];
```

I got the following code snippets so far:

```
        int[][] jaggedArray = new int[3][]
        {
            new int[] { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 },
            new int[] { -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1},
            new int[] { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }
        };

        int[,,] dontWork = new int[,,] // expect 7 everywhere in the last dimension
        {
            { { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 } },
            { { -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1} },
            { { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 } }
        };
```

Comment: I'm confused. Your question asks how to *access* 3D jagged array, but your code seems to indicate you have problems *creating* it. Which one is it?

Comment: I seek an array declaration where afterwards I can access the jagged array like [x,y,z].

I can access the jaggedArray like: jaggedArray[0][1]; // 3 e.g.
The second array declaration causes an error. But I expected it to work like this (or similiar).

Comment: Your `jaggedArray` is not 3D but 2D. And the only what to access it with `jaggedArray[i][j]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for the first question, you're trying to access the 3rd element, of the 2nd element of the 1st element of the jagged array:

```
jaggedArray[1][2][3]
```

As for the error, a 3D array expects the same number of elements in each element of a dimension. Let's say, for simplicity's sake, that you have a 2D jagged array, a rough representation of what that looks like in memory would be:

```
First row  -> 2,   3,  4,  5, 6, 7, 8
Second row -> -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1
Third row  -> 6,   7,  8,  9, 10
```

You can see that each row is seen as a different array, and can therefore differ in size. A multidimensional array, however, does not have this property. It needs to be filled completely:

```
Column    :  0    1   2   3   4  5  6
------------------------------------
First row :  2,   3,  4,  5,  6, 7, 8
Second row: -4,  -3, -2, -1,  0, 1 
Third row :  6,   7,  8,  9, 10
```

Your table is missing some cells, which makes no sense. You need to use the same number of elements per dimension.

Comment: I understand, thank you. 

So my first array declaration is the proper way to go?

Comment: @user1772306 In your case, yes. I prefer multidimensional arrays in most cases, but this is definitely an exception.

Answer (score 3):

You got the syntax for declaring 2D jagged array right, 3D jagged arrays are an extension of that. For example:

```
int[][][] jagged3d = new int[][][]
{
    new int[][] { new int[] { 111, 112 }, new int[] { 121, 122, 123 } },
    new int[][] { new int[] { 211 } }
}
```

But to access it, you need different syntax:

```
jagged3d[0][1][2]
```